In Colab recently : Warning: Plan failed with a cudnnException: CUDNN_BACKEND_EXECUTION_PLAN_DESCRIPTOR: cudnnFinalize Descriptor Failed cudnn_status
As a Colab Pro customer, I am working with PyTorch. Yesterday I got this warning I never got before, quite worrying:
UserWarning: Plan failed with a cudnnException: CUDNN_BACKEND_EXECUTION_PLAN_DESCRIPTOR: cudnnFinalize Descriptor Failed cudnn_status: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED (Triggered internally at ../aten/src/ATen/native/cudnn/Conv_v8.cpp:919.)
Today I launched an older notebook that never raised this warning, and I see that now is also raising this warning.
What is the reason for this?
Is anything wrong? Should  I ignore it?
expected no warnigs as this during training with pytorch, like always
